# regex to ignore curly brackets

Tags: c#, .net, regex

```
{unknown string}  
{unknown string  
unknown string}
unknown string
```

How do I come up with a regex that recognizes just the string (which is unknown, so I cannot do an explicit match to a specific string) in all four of the above cases?

Comment: FYI, what you appear to be calling a "C# Regex" is actually a ".NET Regex". The C# programming language has no support for regular expressions, unlike a language like JavaScript, where such support is built-in.

Comment: .Net is built into C#... sorta.

Comment: @AndreyShchekin That will match the curly braces. He doesn't want those.

Comment: @mcmonkey4eva C# is a language, and a common framework for it is .NET; however there's alternatives such as Mono.

Comment: Mono... being a cross-platform port of .Net...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't tried much, have you?

```
string result = Regex.Match(input, "hello").Value;
```

If you just want something between curly braces:

```
string result = Regex.Match(input, @"\{?(.*)\}?").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Well, that much is true, but I am looking for more generality. Suppose I have the following expression: get { *body* } but I don't know the contents of the body (and hence can't match to a specific string), is there still a way?

Comment: And in the case when there's just one bracket? {^?

Comment: @wemblem It works for that. A `?` means that the character before it is optional.

Answer (score 2):

```
\w+
```

It will match all "word"-characters

If you need to generalize it to something that's "between optional curly braces" you could use:

```
\{?(.+?)\}?
```

which means:

1. `\{?` - an optional curly brace character. It's escaped because `{` has a special meaning in regular expressions. `?` quantifier means `0` or `1` times (thus optional)
2. `(.+?)` - means anything in non-greedy mode. You need non-greedy here so that regex stops right before the following `}` (if any)
3. `\}?` - the same as item #1

Comment: What's the deal with `.+?`? Use `.*` instead. You probably want greedy mode here tbh.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: 1. I'm not sure for `{}` you need to return an empty string as a match, but not match it at all 2. I'm not sure that for `{foo}{bar}` input you need to get `foo}{bar` as a result.

Comment: 1)The content in it is nothing, so I think it should match with nothing. 2) What should it return then? I'm not making a balancing group for this.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: 1. It depends on the task. 2. Perhaps `foo` and `bar`, 2 matches. I'm not good at reading OP's minds this morning, neither you are. So I see all cases as possible until OP states it clearly.

Comment: 1) Agreed. 2) Neither of our solutions do that :P (unless you go into the CaptureCollection for yours)